# Converting JS arrays into objects from table

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

First my solution

```
    function convertTable(table){
  let newArray = []
  for(let i=0; i<table.length-1; i++){
    newArray.push({})
  }
  for(let j=0; j<newArray.length; j++){
     for (const key of table[0]) {
      newArray[j][key] = table[j+1][table[0].indexOf(key)];
      console.log(key)
 }
  }
  return newArray
}
```

What I'm doing is taking an array that holds other arrays which each represents a table row such as

```
const tableData = [
  ["header_one", "header_two", "header_three", "header_four"],
  ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"],
  ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"],
  ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"]
]
```

And making it output

```
    [
  { header_one : "blah", header_two : "blah", header_three: "blah", header_four : "blah" },
  { header_one : "blah", header_two : "blah", header_three: "blah", header_four : "blah" },
  { header_one : "blah", header_two : "blah", header_three: "blah", header_four : "blah" }
]
```

I feel like there must be some better ways to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` to build the desired output.

```js
const tableData = [  ["header_one", "header_two", "header_three", "header_four"],  ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"],  ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"],  ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"]],
      {result} = tableData.reduce((r, arr, i) => {
        if (i) r.result = r.result.concat(r.properties.reduce((a, p, pi) => Object.assign(a, {[p]: arr[pi]}), {}));
        else r.properties = arr;

        return r;
      }, {result: [], properties: []});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` to create the objects, and `.reduce()` on each one to create each object.

```js
const tableData = [
  ["header_one", "header_two", "header_three", "header_four"],
  ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"],
  ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"],
  ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"]
];

const headers = tableData[0];

const result = tableData.slice(1).map(a =>
  a.reduce((o, v, i) => ({...o, [headers[i]]: v}), {})
);

console.log(result);
```

It first separates out the headers, and then uses `.map()` on a slice of the remaining arrays.

In `.reduce()` it uses spread syntax to return a new object with the accumulation so far plus the current header (key) and value.

---

Or here's the same solution, but it swaps the `.reduce()` array to be the headers, with the lookup for the value on the current mapped array.

```js
const tableData = [
  ["header_one", "header_two", "header_three", "header_four"],
  ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"],
  ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"],
  ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"]
];

const headers = tableData[0];

const result = tableData.slice(1).map(a =>
  headers.reduce((o, h, i) => ({...o, [h]: a[i]}), {})
);

console.log(result);
```